# IfAnd macro, but only for first line. Need to add a loop for all lines

Tags: excel, vba

I created a if and, but need to add a loop. Cannot get a loop to work.

```
Sub IfAnd()

If Range("j2") = "9-99-9998" And Range("f2") <> 2 Then
Range("k2").Value = "Indirect"
Else
If Range("j2") = "9-99-9998" And Range("F2") = 2 Then
Range("k2").Value = "IndirectOT"
Else
If Range("j2") <> "9-99-9998" And Range("F2") <> 2 Then
Range("k2").Value = "Direct"
Else
If Range("j2") <> "9-99-9998" And Range("F2") = 2 Then
Range("k2").Value = "DirectOT"
End If
End If
End If
End If

End Sub
```

created an array, but did not work

Comment: Something like `Dim i As Long`, `For i = 2 to 10`, then change each instance of `"J2"`, `"F2"`, and `"K2"` to `"J" & i`, `"F" & i`, and `"K" & i`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub IfAnd()
    Dim r As Long, s As String
    For r = 2 To 3
        If Cells(r, "J") = "9-99-9998" Then
            s = "Indirect"
        Else
            s = "Direct"
        End If
        
        If Cells(r, "F") = 2 Then
            s = s & "OT"
        End If
        Cells(r, "K") = s
   Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Nicely done :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can isolate the If-And checks from the actual loop, which may make it easier in the long run to modify.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim serialNumbers As Range
    Set serialNumbers = Sheet1.Range("J2:J100")

    Dim categories As Range
    Set categories = Sheet1.Range("F2:F100")
    
    Dim laborTypes As Range
    Set laborTypes = Sheet1.Range("K2:K100")
    
    Dim serialNumber As Variant
    For Each serialNumber In serialNumbers
        Dim category As Variant
        For Each category In categories
            Dim laborType As Variant
            For Each laborType In laborTypes
                IfAnd serialNumber, category, laborType
            Next laborType
        Next category
    Next serialNumber
End Sub

Sub IfAnd(serialNumber As Range, category As Range, laborType As Range)
    If (serialNumber = "9-99-9998") And (category <> 2) Then
        laborType = "Indirect"
    ElseIf (serialNumber = "9-99-9998") And (category = 2) Then
        laborType = "IndirectOT"
    ElseIf (serialNumber <> "9-99-9998") And (category <> 2) Then
        laborType = "Direct"
    ElseIf (serialNumber <> "9-99-9998") And (category = 2) Then
        laborType = "DirectOT"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way which **does not** use `Loops`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet1 '<~~ Change this to the relevant sheet
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Range("F" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.Range("K2:K" & LastRow)
    
    With rng
        .Formula = "=IF(J2=""9-99-9998"",IF(F2=2,""IndirectOT"",""Indirect""),IF(F2=2,""DirectOT"", ""Direct""))"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```